# Функция count() при пустых куках показывает 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы когда куки пустые, функция `count()` выводила 0 , а не 1 (как сейчас)?

Куки хранятся в таком виде 4,3,2,1 = ( `4%2C3%2C2%2C1` ).

```
var fav = $.cookie('favorites');
fav = fav.split(","); 

$('.cookie_text').html(fav + " = <span id='wer'>" + count(fav) + "</span>");
```

Функция `count()`:

```
function count(array) {
  var cnt=0;
    for (var i in array){
        if (i){ cnt++ }
    }
 return cnt
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [*split*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) всегда возвращает массив с минимум одним элементом. Это раз.
Два, непонятно что делает ваша функция *count*, если ей на вход подали массив, можно было просто взять его свойство [*length*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

В данном случае может быть несколько вариантов, например

1. проверить, что *fav* пустая строка, значит кук нет.

   ```
   var fav = $.cookie('favorites');
   $('.cookie_text').html(fav + " = <span id='wer'>" + count(fav) + "</span>");

   function count(array){
       if(array==='') return 0;
       return array.split(',').length;
   }
   ```
2. [отфильтровать полученный массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), чтобы убрать элементы с пустой строкой

   ```
   var fav = $.cookie('favorites');
   fav = fav.split(",");
   $('.cookie_text').html(fav + " = <span id='wer'>" + count(fav) + "</span>");

   function count(array){
       return array.filter(function(el){
           return el != '';
       }).length;
   }
   ```

Comment: Хотя я и нашел решение своего вопроса (грубым способом), все таки заменил функцию как вы советовали ( на функцию номер два, первая почему-то плохо работает). Cпасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой вопрос очень просто через `if else`, если перемена не пуста, тогда подсчитываю количество элементов в массиве, а если пустая просто вывожу ноль.

```
var fav_nuul = "0";
var fav = $.cookie('favorites'); 
fav = fav.split(","); 

if (cook != '') { 
    $('.cookie_text').html(fav + " = <span id='wer'>" + count(fav) + "</span>");
} else {
    $('.cookie_text').html(fav + " = <span id='wer'>" + fav_nuul + "</span>");
};
```

Comment: в любом случае стоит пересмотреть функцию _count_, для массивов не рекомендуется использовать цикл _for..in_